# How to prevent malformed tags for XSS

Tags: security, xss, filtering, htmlpurifier, malformed

I read a comment about malformed tags being used for XSS attacks. How am I supposed to sanitize against these. If I use a library like HTMLPurifier, does it take of this as part of its work? or is this an independent thing? I don't hear people talking about it much.

Comment: Can you give an example of these malformed tags that are being used for XSS attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of HTML Purifier's design philosophy is to only output standards compliant HTML, in order to minimize variance in browser interpretation. Thus, HTML Purifier will never output malformed tags.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLPurifier will in fact sanitize for XSS.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it's for, but how about malformed tags?

Comment: It should still take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case HTMLPurifer is overkill.  If XSS is within a tag then you can inject a javascript event without the need of `<>`.  Recently [this happened to twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762746/todays-xss-onmouseover-exploit-on-twitter-com).  The answer is to use `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);`.

Answer (score 0):

In this time and age, to protect yourself fully and completely against XSS, you will need to whitelist rather than blacklist, which HTML Purifier provides. Not only that if put into wrong context even `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);` won't help you, as there are many ways to avoid using both html tags and quotes(stringFromChar, using backslashes), you also have to consider different browser charset, which could allow e.g. this attack in UTF-7 `\\\+ADw-script+AD4-alert(/xss/)+ADw-/script+AD4---//--` to be executed. Although HTMLPurifier does have big overheads, it is a simple non technical way to prevent XSS attacks (although there have been and I believe will have been holes in their filters too).